# Several data points in R on the same date that need to be averaged out to one datapoint

Tags: r, time-series, data-cleaning

I've got a dataframe in R with time series data, and I'm trying to plot how many likes a person got on an instagram post on a given date. However, on some dates a user might post more than once i.e. they will have several datapoints of nr of likes on that date. I'm not sure how I can average out the amount of likes, so that I am left with just one data point.

```
    user <- c('John Doe')
    likecount <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
    postdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2010-11-1','2010-11-2'))

    df <- data.frame(user, likecount, postdate)
```

So for this code example I would need to have the average of the likecount that both fall on the same date. Preferably I would run through the entire dataframe and see if there are several instances of same-day-posting for a single user, where I can automatically average out the likecount on those dates.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(likecount ~ ., df, mean)
```